# SQL Grouping by development type and summation of the value

Tags: mysql

I am working on an api to return a list of building projects.

```
SELECT 
`sample`.`Development Type` AS 'Development Type',
`sample`.`Postcode` AS 'Postcode',
`sample`.`Value Desc` AS 'Value Desc'
FROM
`sample`
WHERE `sample`.`Postcode` LIKE '%SW1%'
```

and this returns a list of building projects.

```
Development Type          | Postcode      | Value Desc

Refurbishment & Extension | SW1E 6LB      | 400,000
Refurbishment & Extension | SW1E 6LB      | 400,000
Refurbishment & Extension | SW1X 8AL      | 75,000
Refurbishment & Extension | SW1X 8AL      | 75,000 
Refurbishment & Extension | SW1P 3RE      | 225,000
Refurbishment & Extension | SW1P 3RE      | 225,000
Extension                 | SW1X 7QU      | 200,000
Extension                 | SW1X 7QU      | 200,000
Refurbishment             | SW1X 8AL      | 75,000
```

I need to modify the query to get an output like this.

```
Development Type          | Sum Value Desc

Refurbishment & Extension | 700,000
Extension                 | 200,000
Refurbishment             | 75,000
```

--so group by Development Type -- remove the duplicate result (could be a flag I should do a where query on, sum in the thousands to handle the comma)

Comment: So to clarify - you wish to deduplicate them first (distinct set) and then sum the distinct set grouped by Development Type?

Comment: yes -- I have found a Project Id col - which is unique

Comment: How does the Project Id column fit into your result set? Should it appear in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a simple `GROUP BY` query if not for that each record seems to appear in duplicate.  But this can fixed by first using a subquery with `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove the duplicates, and then grouping from this subquery to get the sums you want:

```
SELECT t.`Development Type`, FORMAT(SUM(t.`Value Desc`), 0)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT `Development Type`, `Postcode`, `Value Desc`
    FROM sample
) t
GROUP BY t.`Development Type`
ORDER BY SUM(t.`Value Desc`) DESC
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

**Update:**

Since your source data may be in CSV, you can change the outer `SELECT` statement to the following to handle the commas:

```
SELECT t.`Development Type`,
       FORMAT(SUM(CAST(REPLACE(`Value Desc`, ',' , '') AS UNSIGNED)), 0)
```

Also you can change the `ORDER BY` clause to this:

```
ORDER BY SUM(CAST(REPLACE(`Value Desc`, ',' , '') AS UNSIGNED)) DESC
```

Comment: Development Type    | Sum
Extension           | 200
New                 | 0
Refurbishment       | 2375
Refurbishment & Ext | 1053

Comment: @TheOldCounty Use `FORMAT(sum, 0)` if you want commas as a thousands separator.

Comment: @TheOldCounty Get rid of those commas in your input if at all possible.  You are entering your values at _text_, not numbers.  I'm surprised the query runs at all, but in any case it is not giving you the desired result, so drop it, and go with what I have given you.

Comment: Its the way the data came in -- it could be uploaded this way via csv's now and then

Comment: Here is a modification of your Fiddle where everything is now working: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3b7a/15).